# Refresh/Redirect URL while browser is suspended on iOS/Android

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, ios

After a user enters information on a form I have it set to redirect them based on their OS.

- For **iOS** it redirects to my app (i.e. **app://home**),
- For **Android** I have to redirect to a url that prompts the user to open it with my app,
- And finally on a computer it sends them to a url.

The problem I'm facing is that if a user is on iOS or Android and they are redirected to my app if they go back to their web browser it shows the form filled with their information.

My questions is how can I make the webpage refresh to another url after they submit the form after it takes them to use my app so if they go back to the web browser they will be at different webpage.

Meta refresh will not work since when they go to my app the browser is suspended.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice PHP library for detecting mobile clients here: http://mobiledetect.net

Using that it's quite easy to only display content for a mobile:

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
// Check for any mobile device.
if ($detect->isMobile())
// mobile content
else
// other content for desktops
```